# C++ Struct Pointer Segfault

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

First, thanks in advance for all of you who respond to this post.

Second, I've looked through all other posts and couldn't find anything that helped me (my apologies, I'm new to C++).

Here's my code:

```
Node* Insert(Node *head,int data) //for linked lists
{
  Node* current = head;
  while(current -> next != NULL){
      current = current -> next;
  }
  cout << head -> data;
  Node *last = new Node();
  last -> data = data;
  last -> next = NULL;
  current -> next = last;
  return head;
}
```

It seems (by trial and error of line commenting) that the access of the next attribute in the current pointer seems to be the problem, yet I can't seem to figure out why. The Node struct has two attributes, *next (which points to the next item in the linked list) and data (the data of the node).

Any ideas of what's going on?

linuxuser

EDIT: The problem was solved - thanks so much to all who left comments!

Sadly, I wasn't able to use the `**pHead` dereferencing solution, as the problem is on a website that auto-inputs the arguments for the function. Using the comments below, however, I made a simple program that I hope will detail this issue for other beginning C++ programmers like me:

```
Node* Insert(Node *head,int data)
{
    if(head == NULL){
        Node* last = new Node();
        last -> data = data;
        return last;
    }

    Node *current = head;
    while(current -> next != NULL){
        current = current -> next;
    }
    Node *last = new Node();
    last -> data = data;
    last -> next = NULL;
    current -> next = last;
    return head;  
}
```

Regards,

linuxuser

Comment: Also, it seems that when I try `head -> data` I receive a segfault.

Comment: Are you certain `Node`s always get their next value initialized to `NULL`? Perhaps show us how you're initializing the list upon which you operate (i.e. what is head?). Also, this looks like `append()`, not `insert()`.

Comment: Not without more context. What's calling this? Are you sure the caller is passing in a non-null `head`?

Comment: At the very beginning, if `head` is NULL, then you're going to have trouble.  I suggest the first lines of the function should be `cout << head << endl;  cout << head -> data << endl;`

Comment: Thank you all for the fast responses - this is a basic HackerRank problem which gives you a linked list, guaranteeing that *next will always point to another Node or NULL. Also, it is supposed to be append(), but was named (by default) Insert - thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Oh, that's probably it - head is possibly null. I'll try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely issue here is that you cannot use `Insert` to "jump start" your list: if the `head` is `NULL` to start with, the loop is going to fail right away. Moreover, on the first insertion you wouldn't be able to assign the `head`.

To fix this problem, change the first parameter from `Node *head` to `Node **pHead`, pass a pointer to the head pointer, and add an extra level of dereference to the code of your `Insert` function:

```
Node* Insert(Node **pHead, int data)
{
    while(*pHead != NULL){
        pHead = &((*pHead)->next);
    }
    Node *last = new Node();
    last -> data = data;
    last -> next = NULL;
    *pHead = last;
    return last;
}
```

Note that this approach is going to work even if you pass a pointer to `Node` pointer that is set to `NULL`:

```
Node *head = NULL;
Insert(&head, 1);
Insert(&head, 2);
Insert(&head, 3);
```