# Segfault Pointers

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I'm new to C++ and pointers and wrote a simple cpp below. I keep on getting a seg fault, but I'm not sure why.

```
int main() {
    int *x = 0; 
    *x = 8; 
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Where in memory is the `8` being stored?

Comment: Then the close votes should be listed as 'duplicate' not 'off-topic' and there should be comments pointing to the canonical version of the question.  And mixing up pointers and types pointed to is a common problem and not a complete programming topic.  Sure the question title could be better, but to make it so would have required a pre-existing knowledge of the answer.  The questioner provided not only a clear and concise question, minimal reproducible code.

Comment: @Jherico "Pointers" is a whole topic, it really is. If, to someone, it isn't apparent at first glance why `int *x = 0; *x = 8;` is inherently, completely wrong, then that person needs to **learn pointers.** This is not only a "common problem", but the indicator of the fact that OP has no idea about pointers at all. Which is why he should head over to his local library and grab K&R C, instead of wasting our time.

Comment: If you can find a duplicate, please post it so we can direct the user to the correct question.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker With pleasure, [here's one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19885461/c-struct-pointer-segfault), for example.

Comment: @Jherico The title is what will help future visitors from Google. Please try to help everyone out by taking some time to write a clearer title. That way if it's a duplicate it'll be easier to spot duplicates, and if it's not, it'll be easier to claim it isn't. Also, just because a question is closed for the wrong reason doesn't mean it should be re-opened.  Flag it for the correct reason for closure and we'd be happy to close as such.

Comment: The duplicate is far harder to follow for a newcomer since it doesn't show all of the involved code and it involves a custom structure that references itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your integer pointer is null. See this line:

```
int *x =0
```

On that line you're setting the memory address of your integer pointer to zero (i.e. nullptr). What I expect you wanted to do is set the value to zero, in which case you'd need to do this:

```
int main() {
  int *x = new int(0);
  *x = 8;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You've declared a pointer to an integer and set it to 0.  You haven't actually allocated an integer anywhere.  When you assign 8 to the dereferenced pointer, you're trying to write to the memory at location 0.  All modern operating systems read and write product the memory at address 0 and anywhere near it to prevent this kind of 'null pointer error'.

Think of memory on a computer as a sheet of graph paper.  Each square on the paper has an address, which is the number of squares that came before it.  Pointers are for storing these addresses.  An `int` is an actual value, like '5 apples' or '12 downvoting asshats'.  These are the values that are stored by writing a number inside one of the rectangles.

However, the OS that manages the system knows that one of the most common kinds of errors people make is forgetting to set up a pointer properly and attempting to write numbers at the very start of the graph paper, so it's designed the graph paper to give you an electric shock if you try to write a number in any of the first few boxes.  This is your segmentation fault.

To fix the issue you can either declare an integer on the stack

```
int i;
int * x = &i;
```

Declaring something on the stack means the memory will automatically be freed when it leaves scope, i.e. the end of the function.

On the other hand you can allocate a pointer on the heap

```
int * x = new int;
```

this means that you're personally responsible for making sure that you free the memory at some later point.

```
delete x;
```

Otherwise you're creating a memory leak.

Comment: is this by definition a segmentation fault then? Sorry, I'm trying to get familiar with terminology as well

Comment: How the error shows up will vary by compiler and OS, but yes, the segmentation fault is coming as soon as you try to write to the memory, because the OS has the memory at location 0 marked as inaccessible.  On Unix / Linux, the OS will immediately stop your program with a segmentation fault.

Answer (score 1):

When you define `int *x = 0`, what you're telling the compiler is "create a integer pointer, x, and set where it points to to 0 (NULL)". What you need to do instead is dynamically create a new pointer. This can be achieved by doing `int *x = new int;` Then you can change its value. After using it, you should delete it using `delete x;` to free up its memory.

Answer (score 1):

```
int *x = 0;
```

You made an int pointer called `x` which points to the memory at location 0.

```
*x = 8;
```

You tried to write the value 8 into the memory at location 0, which was stored in `x`. Since this memory is not owned by you, the OS terminated you.

Answer (score 1):

Let's break this down a bit:

```
int *x = 0
```

this line creates a pointer called x and points it to NULL (or nowhere)

```
*x = 8
```

There is an immediate issue here as soon as you "dereference" x, meaning asking for the spaces associated what x points to.

Since you pointed x at NULL you're asking for the int located at NULL. This is illegal as NULL is an invalid memory space causing a seg-fault.